# Error sending json in POST to web API service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a web service using Web API. I implemented a simple class

```
public class ActivityResult
{
    public String code;
    public int indexValue;
    public int primaryCodeReference;
}
```

And then I have implemented inside my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ActivityResult ar)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

But when I call the API passing in POST the file json:

```
{"code":"XXX-542","indexValue":"3","primaryCodeReference":"7"}
```

I obtain the following error message:

```
{
    "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'ActivityResult' from content with media type 'text/plain'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
    "StackTrace": "   in System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   in System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   in System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to add a header of "application/json" for the payload to be accepted from the client.

Comment: I have correctly setted the headers in my HTTP request. However the  problem seems to be server-side: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xlidnnybs8v6d0u/Cattura.JPG

Comment: It looks like you're only setting the `Accept` header to `application/json`.  You also need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

In the HTTP request you need to set Content-Type to: `Content-Type: application/json`

So if you're using fiddler client add `Content-Type: application/json` to the request header

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to must add header property `Content-Type:application/json`
2. When you define any POST request method input parameter that should be annotated as `[FromBody]`, *e.g.*:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]ActivityResult ar)
   {
     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
   }
   ```
3. Any JSON input data must be *raw* data.

Answer (score 1):

another tip...where to add "content-type: application/json"...to the textbox field on the Composer/Parsed tab.  There are 3 lines already filled in there, so I added this Content-type as the 4th line.  That made the Post work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are were passing method as `POST` instead as `GET`.
if so you will get same error as a you posted above.

```
$http({               
 method: 'GET',
```

> The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for
>   this resource.

Comment: The question is specifically about a http POST, he's not requesting data from the server he's sending data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had all my settings covered in the accepted answer.
The problem I had was that I was trying to update the Entity Framework entity type "Task" like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(Task task)
```

What worked for me was to create my own entity "DTOTask" like:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(DTOTask task)
```

Answer (score 0):

It require to include `Content-Type:application/json` in web api request header section when not mention any content then  by default it is `Content-Type:text/plain` passes to request.

Best way to test api on postman tool.