# ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'user' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data in "postman"

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler, postman

I am creating the Login Service using Web API. When I am checking with `fiddler` it's working fine but when I am checking with `postman` of `chrome` it's showing error:

```
{    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'user' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace": "   
    at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)\r\n
    at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)\r\n
    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)\r\n
    at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n
    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteBindingAsync>b__0(HttpParameterBinding parameterBinder)\r\n
    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n
    at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.IterateImpl(IEnumerator`1 enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" 
}
```

```
public class user
{
    //public user(string userId, string password)
    //{
    //    UserId = userId;
    //    Password = password;
    //}

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I am checking in `postman` if this service is able to access in mobile application. Also, to check this in mac system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click on the Header button type this both header and value

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

check below link for fiddle and postman both use same content-types
[Error sending json in POST to web API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384354/error-sending-json-in-post-to-web-api-service)

Comment: I try on POSTMAN of Chrome Navigator and works fine with this header value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I run into same problem but later I figured it out that I was calling WebAPI 
using ajax POST instead I changed it to GET and it worked. But error was mostly misguiding. So all the time I was focusing on media type.

**The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",**

```
$http({             
method: 'POST',
```

Change it to

```
$http({             
method: '**GET**',
```