# Why getting null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I am testing my web api via postman. But getting the passed request object as null.

Below is WebAPI action.

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("rename")]
    public IHttpActionResult Rename([FromBody]Customer custObj)
    {

        //I am getting custObj always null
    }
```

Initially, I got the below error.

> Error sending json in POST to web API service

Using the below link, I came to know that I missed to set the `content-type:application/json`
[Error sending json in POST to web API service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384354/error-sending-json-in-post-to-web-api-service)

After setting the content type, the API method is hit but I am getting the customer object as null.

[image: Postman]

```
public class Customer
{
   public int UserId {get; set;}

   public string Title {get; set;}


  //& so on
}
```

Any help/suggestion highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please include your Customer object in the question?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog, Customer class added in the post

Comment: I'm assuming that you have properties for UserId, Type and Title as well in the Customer object?

Edit: Could you include them, with their correct types, in the question?

Comment: @JoakimSkoog, Yes. Correct

Comment: Have you tried actually passing through a json object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In POSTMAN,

Select "raw" instead of "form-data"

Select "JSON (application/json)" instead of (default) "Text"

Paste

```
{
    "UserId": 1,
    "Type": "Gold",
    "Title": "Test rename api via postman"
}
```

Click "Send"

Comment: Yes.right. Got the data. But is it the only way to set the object in Postman?/

Comment: @Kgn-web I suppose it is, and OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending it as

```
"customer": {
  "userid": 1,
  "title": "something"
}
```

and include this as json